# Client unable to find socket.io when running my website from online host but works from localhost (I WILL VENMO YOU $10 IF YOU HELP ME FIX THIS)

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io, webserver

I have looked at and tried over 10 different solutions to this but nothing seems to work and I'm at a loss. I have tried having the src in my HTML file be "http://Mywebsite.com:80/socket.io/socket.io.js", I have tried changing around the order of my server code, and I have tried having the client specifically point to my website's ip address.

None of it seems to work. When I run this on localhost, it works great with no problems whatsoever but whenever my webserver, I get the following error as seen in the inspect panel. Willing to try anything and thanks in advance!

[image: Client error]

[image: HTML Code]

[image: Server code]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like javascript file where the socket.io library was is not in your webserver. Try changing the source file of the library to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.1/socket.io.js`